# I have two timers ones not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer

In my tank game (not unlike awesome tanks for reference) I want my AI tank to also shoot a bullet so I made another timer but when i try to run it says the `AItimer` is not defined in `clearInterval(AItimer);` I am confused because the code is from another timer but it works fine.

```js
function aiStartTimer() {
  if (shoot == 0) {
    //creates aitimer variable
    AItimer = setInterval("aiFireBullet()", 100);
    shoot = 1 * 1;
  } else if (shoot == 1) {
    clearInterval(AItimer);
    shoot = 0 * 1;
  }
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tm9oL74r/)

Comment: if this function is being called from anywhere in your script you should define AItimer as a global variable outside of the function like `var AItimer;`

Comment: Correct syntax : `setInterval(aiFireBullet,100);` The first argument of `setInterval` should be a function, you gave it a string

Comment: The overload of `setTimeout` which takes a string as its first argument is not recommended for use as it is essentially the same as using `eval()`.

Comment: @JeremyThille While a reference is *strongly* preferred, code-as-a-string is just fine.

Comment: Do you use the same variable, `AItimer`, in your other timer?

Comment: Unrelated, but I don't understand why you set `shoot` to the results of a multiplication. Or just use a boolean.

Comment: Ha, the more you know. I've never seen anybody passing `setInterval` a string, ever.

Comment: @JeremyThille Yeah, it's a bad idea in general. It was pretty common early on; I don't know if `setTimeout` only used to take a string or what--don't recall.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the order it works so if I have learned something order is important

Comment: Not at all clear what this means; the question lacks enough context to (a) help and (b) make your answer make sense.

Answer (score -1):

1. I do not know if ai timer is declared but it probably is
2. `setInterval` does not need a string or `()`. Proper syntax for `setInterval` is `setInterval(aiFireBullet, 100)`
3. For the `shoot` variable you do not need to use `1 * 1` or `0 * 1`, just use `shoot = 1` and `shoot = 0`

Comment: `setTimeout` works just fine with a string. It's not *recommended*, for a variety of reasons. Unrelated, but it's hard to read this answer.